# undefined method `bootstrap_wysihtml5' in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I am trying to integrate[Bootstrap wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/)! editor in railsadmin. I am aware of [this guide](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Wysihtml5) and I following same. I added my code below.

```
config.model Region do

list do
  field :name
  field :description
  field :seos
  field :active
  field :publish
end

create do
  field :name
  field :description do
    bootstrap_wysihtml5 true
  end
  field :seos
end

update do
  field :name
  field :description do
    bootstrap_wysihtml5 true
  end
  field :seos
end
end
```

I am getting following Error

```
undefined method `bootstrap_wysihtml5' for # <RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::Text:0x007fd3f27e6198> (NoMethodError)
```

I also tried another method mention in wiki

```
config.model Region do
    list do
      field :name
      field :description
      field :seos
      field :active
      field :publish
    end

    create do
      field :name
      field :description , :wysihtml5
      field :seos
    end

    update do
      field :name
      field :description , :wysihtml5
      field :seos
    end
end
```

I am getting following error again.

```
Unsupported field datatype: wysihtml5 (RuntimeError)
```

Offcourse I added the

```
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'
```

in gemfile and done bundle install. Any help will save lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I was using version of Rails admin and Jquery Rails. As soon as updating it , it working perfectly.

```
gem 'rails_admin', "~>0.4.3"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.1"
```